# forming sub-query in MySQL within a databse

Tags: mysql

List the customer number, customer name, and sales rep that have the same rep number as customer number 282. This will need to be a subquery and do not test for sales rep 35 explicitly.

```
 use premier_products;

SELECT customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, rep.first_name 
FROM rep 
JOIN customer ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num 
WHERE customer_num = 282;
```

im confused with how to form a subquery with the following question. the only two fileds that are related between the two tables is rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num.i know how to form it the reguar way but need to understand how to form it in subquery.

AND `REP.FIRST_NAME` REFERS TO SALES REP...

**schema'**

```
CREATE DATABASE premier_products;
```

**Rep Table**

```
CREATE TABLE rep
(
rep_num char(2) primary key,

last_name varchar(15),

first_name varchar(15),

street varchar(15),

city varchar(15),

state char(2),

zip char(5),

commission decimal(7,2),

rate decimal(3,2) 

);
```

**Customer table**

```
CREATE TABLE customer

(

customer_num char(3) primary key, 

customer_name varchar(30),

street varchar(15),

city varchar(15),

state char(15),

zip char(5),

balance decimal(7,2),

credit_limit decimal(7,2),

rep_num char(2)

);
```

**Orders table**

```
CREATE TABLE orders

(

order_num char(5) primary key,

order_date timestamp,

customer_num char(3)

);
```

**Order_line table**

```
CREATE TABLE order_line

(

order_num char(5),

part_num char(4),

num_ordered int(5),

quoted_price decimal(7,2),

PRIMARY KEY (order_num, part_num)

);
```

**Part table**

```
CREATE TABLE part

(

part_num char(4) primary key,

description varchar(20),

on_hand int(4),

class char(2),

warehouse char(2),

price decimal (7,2)
);
```

**Populate rep table**

```
INSERT INTO rep values ('20', 'Kaiser', 'Valerie', '624 Randall', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 20542.50, 0.05);

INSERT INTO rep values ('35', 'Hull', 'Richard', '532 Jackson', 'Sheldon', 'FL', '33553', 39216.00, 0.07);

INSERT INTO rep values ('65', 'Perez', 'Juan', '1626 Taylor', 'Fillmore', 'FL', '33336', 23487.00, 0.05);
```

**Populate customer table**

```
INSERT INTO customer values ('148', 'Al''s Appliance and Sport', '2837 Greenway', 'Fillmore', 'FL', '33336',
6550.00, 7500.00, '20');

INSERT INTO customer values ('282', 'Brookings Direct', '3827 Devon', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 431.50, 10000.00, '35');

INSERT INTO customer values ('356', 'Ferguson''s', '382 Wildwood', 'Northfield', 'FL', '33146', 5785.00, 7500.00,
'65');

INSERT INTO customer values ('408', 'The Everything Shop', '1828 Raven', 'Crystal', 'FL', '33503', 5285.25, 5000.00, '35');

INSERT INTO customer values ('462', 'Bargains Galore', '3829 Central', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 3412.00, 10000.00, '65');

INSERT INTO customer values ('524', 'Kline''s', '838 Ridgeland', 'Fillmore', 'FL', '33336', 12762.00, 15000.00, '20');

INSERT INTO customer values ('608', 'Johnson''s Department Store', '372 Oxford', 'Sheldon', 'FL', '33553', 2106.00, 10000.00, '65');

INSERT INTO customer values ('687', 'Lee''s Sport and Appliance', '282 Evergreen', 'Altonville', 'FL', '32543', 2851.00, 5000.00, '35');

INSERT INTO customer values ('725', 'Deerfield''s Four Seasons', '282 Columbia', 'Sheldon', 'FL', '33553', 248.00, 7500.00, '35');

INSERT INTO customer values ('842', 'All Season', '28 Lakeview', 'Grove', 'FL', '33321', 8221.00, 7500.00, '20');
```

**Populate orders table**

```
INSERT INTO orders value ('21608', '2015-10-20', '148');

INSERT INTO orders value ('21610', '2015-10-20', '356');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21613', '2015-10-21', '408');

INSERT INTO orders value ('21614', '2015-10-21', '282');

INSERT INTO orders value ('21617', '2015-10-23', '608');
INSERT INTO orders value ('21619', '2015-10-23', '148');

INSERT INTO orders value ('21623', '2015-10-23', '608');
```

**Populate order_line table**

```
INSERT INTO order_line value ('21608', 'AT94', 11, 21.95);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21610', 'DR93', 1, 495.00);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21610', 'DW11', 1, 399.99);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21613', 'KL62', 4, 329.95);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21614', 'KT03', 2, 595.00);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21617', 'BV06', 2, 794.95);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21617', 'CD52', 4, 150.00);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21619', 'DR93', 1, 495.00);

INSERT INTO order_line value ('21623', 'KV29', 2, 1290.00);
```

**Populate part table**

```
INSERT INTO part value ('AT94', 'Iron', 50, 'HW', '3', 24.95);

INSERT INTO part value ('BV06', 'Home Gym', 45, 'SG', '2', 794.95);

INSERT INTO part value ('CD52', 'Microwave Oven', 32, 'AP', '1', 165.00);

INSERT INTO part value ('DL71', 'Cordless Drill', 21, 'HW', '3', 129.95);

INSERT INTO part value ('DR93', 'Gas Range', 8, 'AP', '2', 495.00);

INSERT INTO part value ('DW11', 'Washer', 12, 'AP', '3', 399.99);

INSERT INTO part value ('FD21', 'Stand Mixer', 22, 'HW', '3', 159.95);

INSERT INTO part value ('KL62', 'Dryer', 12, 'AP', '1', 349.95);

INSERT INTO part value ('KT03', 'Dishwasher', 8, 'AP', '3', 595.00);

INSERT INTO part value ('KV29', 'Treadmill', 9, 'SG', '2', 1390.00);
```

Comment: "i know how to form it the reguar way" - Please post your "regular" solution. However you need a subquery in the WHERE clause.

Comment: SELECT customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, rep.first_name, rep.rep_num
FROM rep
JOIN customer
ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num
WHERE customer_num = 282;

Comment: I know this way but not sure how to form sub query

Comment: PLease add schema and sample data for both tables.

Comment: how would i add that?

Comment: edit the question

Comment: i added the schema

Comment: the person who answered below was on the right track but not sire why he added customer_id

Comment: This looks a lot like a homework question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try following query:

```
 SELECT customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, rep.first_name 
    FROM rep 
    JOIN customer ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num
    WHERE rep.first_name = (Select rep.first_name FROM rep 
    JOIN customer ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num where customer.customer_num = 282);
```

Alternatively, you can store the rep of customer 282 in a variable and just use it in where clause. In that way, you can reuse that value in no of queries without using a subquery like following:

```
SET @rep:= (Select rep.first_name FROM rep 
   inner JOIN customer ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num where customer.customer_num = 282);     

 SELECT customer.customer_num, customer.customer_name, rep.first_name 
        FROM rep 
        JOIN customer ON rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num
        WHERE rep.first_name = @rep;
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: the word as is inavlid syntax it says

Comment: EDITED THE QUERY...Check it out

Comment: that didn't work either. result is not found in database

Comment: the edited query works but it still displays other result rather than just customer 282. it displays two other customer numbers but i dont know why since 282 is specified

Comment: It shows other records as well because you asked for it in the question :"List the customer number, customer name, and sales rep that have the same rep number as customer number 282" It means details of all customer who has same rep as customer num 282.

Comment: all names are under Richard but i guess thats just the answer

Comment: You're welcome. Some useful tips to keep in mind while asking questions here: Always add schema, sample data, query you've tried so far, error(if any). current output & desired output. Don't add insert and create queries unless that's one with the problem. Only add tables or schemas that are needed for the asked problem. Get some basic guidelines from here:  https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.

```
 select customer.customer_num,customer.customer_name 
    from customer 
    where customer_id 
         in (SELECT rep_num   
                 from rep,customer  
                      where rep.rep_num = customer.rep_num   
                         and customer_num = 282)
```

Comment: why did you add customer_id into the query?